# <!-- #include virtual="/footer.asp"--> in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

I need to include a header and footer currently located in an asp page. The page takes the language ID and gives you the correct header for the page you are viewing.

I was going thru this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1420472.aspx and this particular fragment seemed to explain it better tho I could not wrap my mind around it.

> *Hi, instead of using include tags, you could compose your page this way:
>    
>       
>           Your .NET application here
>          You can
>   then implement in codebehind remote
>   header and footer download logic and
>   set them in the Literals' Text. After
>   downloading from the remote site, I
>   would suggest to store the header and
>   footer in the application's Cache to
>   avoid too many connections to the
>   remote server. If the same
>   header-and-footer are shared from many
>   pages in your project, moving this
>   structure to a MasterPage could be
>   useful.*

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it would be applicable if header/footer content is coming from some other (remote) server. So the suggested solution is to

1. Write code to download header/footer content from remote server
2. Cache the content so that you don't have to download it again and again.
3. Use literal controls as placeholders on page and set its text to this downloaded content from code-behind.

Now, this may or may not be applicable to your problem. From where does you get the content for header/footer. If its some helper class/method then you can directly call it to set the literal text. You can even do that is master page making things even simpler.

Edit: Additional information requested by OP

You can use WebRequest for downloading content. See this article to get started.: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebrequest/dotnetwebrequest.htm

Refer below to get started on caching:

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-cache-object-to-cache-application-information

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. How do I go about downloading the header and footer and setting up the cache. I am pretty new on this.

Comment: This is how it works. The asp page has a sub that practically just takes the language id. In essence I need a way to call that sub from my asp.net code behind and fetch the results.

Comment: The caching link came in very handy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to get the required footer text from the asp page and then use the [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz4949ks%28VS.80%29.aspx) control to display this text.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) has an example code about how you can submit value to a page and get the response.

Comment: The asp page has a function that accepts a parameter. How do I call that function using HttpWebRequest

Comment: I am not seeing an instance where a sub is called in the request. It seems more like its posting data to the URL using POST. Is that right?

Comment: just make a call to the abc.asp?id=12345 ... thats all

Comment: On another note.. a simple google search would give you the answerfor GET.

Comment: Thanks, currently looking at the sample: The page is called like this within asp pages <%DISPLAY_BANNER "en", ""%>. So in this case I would jst pass the langID and not even mention the name of the method expecting it?